# Working on my second project and I'm confused about proper procedure for turning on the arduino

Tags: arduino-ide

The first project I did was just making the led blink (it was pulsing a signal to pin 13. I'm guessing most of you have seen similar tutorials).

Today I plugged in some wires and resistors and wrote a program for a volt meter.

How am I to stop the pulses on the output pins from my previous project from messing everything up in the newer project in that interval of time after plugging in the usb and before compiling/ uploading the new code?

The question occurred to me when I saw the led blinking from the last project, before I could hit the upload button... maybe I'm wrong, but I'm envisioning this causing problems for me in the future as my circuits become more and more complex.

Comment: Just upload a blank sketch (only `void setup() {} void loop() {}`) before you start.

Answer (score 1):

If you've rewired an Arduino board for a new project, such that outputs from the currently-loaded sketch may cause problems, temporarily jumper from ground to Reset, to hold the MCU (ATmega328, etc.) in reset until you are ready to load the new sketch.  Pull the jumper upon starting a download, of either your new project or an empty sketch as suggested in Majenko's comment.  Typically, Arduinos are reset at the beginning of each download.

Arduino boards (Uno, Nano, Mega, et al) that use an additional chip (FT232, Atmega16U2 or 32U4, CH340G, etc) as a USB interface should be able to register as USB devices even when the MCU is reset.  Arduino boards without a separate USB chip (Leonardo, Micro, et al) should not.

Comment: Someone voted this down, which is absolutely their prerogative, but I'm voting it up because it is a possible (if somewhat complex) solution. :)

Comment: @NickGammon, it's true that loading an empty sketch, or the new sketch, before attaching the new hardware is a better approach.  But if a board gets built in to controlled equipment before the old sketch is removed, powering it up not-reset  could be risky.  Is there a simpler approach than keeping the board reset?

Comment: The timing can be dodgy (you need to release reset fairly precisely) but I agree it is a viable solution, which is why I voted for it.

Comment: It is also a recommended solution for escaping from a sketch that has a watchdog timer set so quickly that the bootloader can't load.